# Как выровнять блок по центру, без абсолютного позиционирования

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Я пытаюсь выровнять блок по центру `.container`, но что-то идёт не так, изменять можно только свойства `.new__post` и html этого элемента, но родителей через html и css нельзя трогать. Нужно, чтобы элемент не выпадал из потока, т.е. не задавать ему `position: absolute`

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.burger__menu .container {
    padding: 10px 10px 60px;
    height: auto;
}

.new__post {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="burger__menu">
 <div class="container">

  <div class="new__post">
   <a href="../new_post.php">Написать пост</a>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .container -->

</div> <!-- .burger__menu -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Я использую обычно такой способ, он мне удобен, но возможно есть какие-то более интересные решения?

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.burger__menu .container {
    padding: 10px 10px 60px;
    height: auto;
}

.new__post {
 max-width: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="burger__menu">
 <div class="container">

  <div class="new__post">
   <a href="../new_post.php">Написать пост</a>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .container -->

</div> <!-- .burger__menu -->
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin: 0 auto` не сработает в паре с `display:inline-block`. Вот:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.burger__menu .container {
    padding: 10px 10px 60px;
    height: auto;
    background:silver;
}

.new__post {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
  width:50%;
  background:pink;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="burger__menu">
 <div class="container">

  <div class="new__post">
   <a href="../new_post.php">Написать пост</a>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .container -->

</div> <!-- .burger__menu -->
```